# How can i write session variable in view in cakephp 2?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I read the cakephp documentation but there example is given how to write session vairable in controller like following.

```
$this->Session->write('Name', 'Value');
```

In a situation, I need to write session variable in view. How can i achieve that.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what problem you're trying to fix by writing session data from a view? Perhaps there's a better solution.

Comment: Best you keep views to... Presenting a view. Do your logic in models or controllers. No need to do CRUD operations in views

Answer (score 2):

The question is old but the answer may help someone. To write SESSION in view use.

```
<?php SessionComponent::write('Name', 'Value'); ?>
```

And to read it use

```
$this->Session->read('Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the Session in views, only read. All Session writing is done in the Controller.

But if you really need, and I highly do not recommend doing this, write to the Session in the view you can use AJAX to call a method that writes whatever you need into the Session.

Comment: AJAX? If you're going to break the MVC pattern, you could probably just write into `$_SESSION`.

Comment: That's why I added "if he really needs to". I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: To be clear - working with sessions is done via Session `component` and component can be used in controllers and / or another components, not only controller as you mentioned.